# What's the difference between "someone" and "somebody"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, indefinite-pronouns

What is the difference between "someone is waiting for me" and "somebody is waiting for me?" Please make it clear for me.

Comment: Yeah there is difference

Comment: @user78248 there is a difference between *some body* and *somebody*.

Comment: The difference is that _someone_ has two syllables and _somebody_ has three. That can matter, to enough people. Enough to keep both forms common in native speakers' usage, anyway.

Answer (score -2):

*Someone* is used if we don’t know the person and there are many people to decide from. *Somebody* is used when we refer to a person, but in a narrow amount of selection.

Comment: This does not match any usage of _someone_ and _somebody_ that I’ve ever come across.